# promisse value undefined axios

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, axios

I'm trying to get values using axios and on my browser returns [[PromisseValue]] undefined. Follow my code. Please, help-me... thanks
[This is my data to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKrtZ.png)

```
 <script>
    export default {
        props: ['endpoint'],
        data () {
            return {
                response: {
                    table: '',
                    displayable: [],
                    records: []
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getRecords () {
                return axios.get(`${this.endpoint}`).then((response) => {
                   console.log(response.data.data.table)
                })
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            this.getRecords()
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what's the problem? If the promise is resolving to allow you to log the response to the console (per your screenshot), where are you getting `undefined`?

Comment: Does console.log output smth ? seems like you are not returning response after console.log

Comment: For debuggin purposes just print the response object

Comment: Also add catch to the promise to handle errors

Comment: @fubar In my methods I put this.response = response.data.data. In my view still empty. When I look on chrome dev tools shows me [[PromisseValue]] undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will return promise because AXIOS is a promise function that you are trying to return.

```
axios.get(`${this.endpoint}`).then((response) => {
   this.response.table = response.data.data.table
})
```

after axios call you need save it into your state or data the response then use it wherever you want.

Comment: Maybe, my problem was on my logic to show the data. Let me try to explain better

Comment: Maybe, my problem was on my logic to show the data. Let me try to explain better. 1 - I have a abstract DataTableController to Build and get data ('data' => ['table', 'thead', 'values']), from any table, in this case i'm using Users Table and the Json return successfully. 2 The props 'endpoint' is my url, respondes successfully, function data (), to return my values form axios.get, apparently return, but on my view it`s empty. `axios.get(`${this.endpoint}`).then((response) => { this.response = response.data.data }).catch((error) => { if(error){ console.log(error)} }) ` status 200.

Comment: Ohhh.. I change (=>) for .then(function(response) and returns me response undefined...